# Why zsh doesn't print string which doesn't contain new line?

Tags: zsh

I found that zsh do not print string which doesn't contain new line.
Here is example:

```
[240 ~]>echo -n "35" > js.id
[240 ~]>cat js.id
[240 ~]>xxd -p js.id
3335
```

If file `js.id` contains new line, zsh would nomally print all string.

```
[240 ~]>echo "35" > js.id
[240 ~]>cat js.id
35
[240 ~]>xxd -p js.id
33350a
```

BTW, here is my setopt config:

```
[240 ~]>setopt PROMPT_CR PROMPT_SP
setopt: no such option: PROMPT_SP
[240 ~]>setopt
interactive
login
monitor
shinstdin
zle
[240 ~]>echo -n 'str'
[240 ~]>echo 'str'
str
```

Comment: Which version of zsh is this? Ps, Are you sure you are running zsh?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you (or some config you copied?) unset option `PROMPT_SP` or `PROMPT_CR`?

Start zsh ignoring all config files to verify that, by default, it does display such a file:

```
 ~ % zsh -f
 % echo -n 35 > int.txt   
 % cat int.txt 
 35%
 %
```

Notice that Zsh will display a `%` at the end of your file if it does not end on a newline (`PROMPT_SP`).

Comment: I do have no such two options `PROMPT_SP` an `PROMPT_CR`. I tried to set these two options, but failed. `setopt PROMPT_SP` says `setopt: no such option: PROMPT_SP` , `setopt PROMPT_CR` says nothing. Anything wrong with my zsh?

Comment: start the shell again explicitly with `zsh` issue those commands. You are most likely not running zsh (for whatever reason). Also call `ps` (without any flags) and later `ps -f`. that will help you determine what exactly you are running.

Comment: `[xuehui1@lamp2]~% echo $ZSH_VERSION
4.2.6
[xuehui1@lamp2]~% ps -f
UID        PID  PPID  C STIME TTY          TIME CMD
xuehui1  25070 25069  0 19:28 pts/0    00:00:00 -zsh
xuehui1  25637 25070  0 19:31 pts/0    00:00:00 ps -f`

Comment: I don't know how old that is, but perhaps you should try to upgrade?